Difference in swiftBar.refreshOnOpen for fingerprint vs password login
I am a first-time AppleScript/Automator user trying to understand a behavior I observed in my .sh file for a SwiftBar plugin. The relevant line of code is:
<swiftbar.refreshOnOpen>true</swiftbar.refreshOnOpen>
The script automatically runs when I log in to my macOS account via fingerprint (touch ID) on my MacBook but not when I log in using my password.
Why does the script run automatically only on fingerprint login?
